# strongloop loopback GET ressource/exists vs HEAD ressource

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

With strongloop's loopback default REST API for persisted model, what is the difference between doing:

- `HEAD Ressource/{id}`
- `GET Ressource/{id}/exists`

?

Comment: Interesting question, both should be same I guess!

Comment: After giving it some thoughts, I have the feeling ```GET exist/``` is to respect REST conventions, while HEAD is more making use of http capabilities. Does that makes sense ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an interesting question. I checked out and found out only two difference.

Exist API

```
http://0.0.0.0:3001/api/brands/1/exists
```

returns

```
{
  "exists": true
}
```

or

```
{
  "exists": false
}
```

Response Code is 200 for both conditions.

HEAD API

```
http://0.0.0.0:3001/api/brands/1
```

returns `no content` on both condition.

**Response Code** is 200 when exists and 404 when doesn't exists.